# How can I call function from other function in C

Tags: c, c-strings, palindrome, function-definition

I try to cod C program where the user can input a string and the program should check if the string is Palindrome or not. The string can also be a sentence such as "no lemon, no melon". I have a function "checkForSpaceAndChar" that removes spaces from the sentence and another function "isPalindrome" that checks if the string is Palindrome. Now I try to figure out how I can first take the entered string and remove the space and special characters and then check if the string is a palindrome.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

int isPalindrome(char inputeString[]){
    int begin = 0, end = strlen(inputeString) - 1;

    while (end > 1) {
        if (inputeString[begin++] != inputeString[end--]) {
            return 0;
        }
        else {
            return 1;
        }
    }
}

char checkForSpaceAndChar(char stringWithoutSpace[], char newArray[]) {

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(stringWithoutSpace); i++) {
        if (isalpha(stringWithoutSpace[i]) != 0) {
            stringWithoutSpace[i] = newArray[i];
        }
    }
}
#define SIZE 1000

int main(void) {
    int repeat = 1;
    char arrayPalindrome[SIZE], newArray[SIZE];

    while (repeat == 1) {
        printf("Enter a sentence: ");
        scanf("%s", arrayPalindrome);

        checkForSpaceAndChar(arrayPalindrome, newArray);

        if (isPalindrome(arrayPalindrome) == 0) {
            printf("This sentence is not a palindrome.");
        }
        if (isPalindrome(arrayPalindrome) == 1) {
            printf("This sentence is a palindrome.");
        }
        printf("\n\nDo you want to enter another sentence (0 for no, 1 for yes)?");
        scanf_s("%d", &repeat);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have described what you want to do but you have not described what specific error or problem you have with the code as shown.

Comment: `isPalindrome()` is not correct. It always returns during the first iteration of the loop, so it just checks whether the first character is the same as the last character. `return 1` should be after the loop, not in `else`.

Comment: OT: It is inefficient to call `isPalidrome` twice. Just call it once and save the return value. Though in this case it's more common to have an `if () { ..} else { .. }` rather than checking the return value twice.

Comment: `scanf("%s")` has all the same issue as `gets`.  Never use `gets`.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used  As a direct corollary, never use `scanf("%s"...)`

Comment: regarding: `for (int i = 0; i < strlen(stringWithoutSpace); i++) {`  the function: `strlen()` returns a `size_t` which is a unsigned value.  This statement is comparing it to a `int` which is a signed value.

Comment: two of the posted functions have an execution path that does not end in a `return value` statement, however, the function signatures say the returned type is not `void`

Comment: OT: a palindrome can be checked by only comparing 1/2 of the characters.  When the comparison reaches the middle of the char array, there is no need to continue comparing

Answer (score 1):

`checkForSpaceAndChar()` needs to use two index variables, one for the input array and another for the output array. The way you've written it, it copies all the alpha characters to `newArray`, but leave the elements corresponding to the non-alpha characters unchanged. So you get gaps of uninitialized entries.

And it should be copying in the other direction, from `stringWithoutSpace` to `newArray`.

Since `checkForSpaceAndChar` doesn't return anything, it should be declared `void`.

```
void checkForSpaceAndChar(char stringWithoutSpace[], char newArray[]) {
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(stringWithoutSpace); i++) {
        if (isalpha(stringWithoutSpace[i]) != 0) {
            newArray[j++] = stringWithoutSpace[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Since `newArray` is where it copies to, you need to use that as the argument to `isPalindrome()`.

```
        if (isPalindrome(newArray)) {
            printf("This sentence is a palindrome.");
        } else {
            printf("This sentence is not a palindrome.");
        }
```

Comment: checkForSpaceAndChar doesn't return a value.  Maybe that should be a void func?

Answer (score 0):

To check whether a sequence of alpha characters of a string form a palindrome there is no need to remove non-alpha characters. Moreover if the user will pass a string literal as a function argument then such a function that removes non-alpha characters will invoke undefined behavior..

So such an approach is not good.

The function `isPalindrome` can be written for example the following way without the requirement to remove non-alpha characters.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>


int isPalindrome( const char *s )
{
    const char *p = s + strlen( s );

    do
    {
        while ( s != p && !isalpha( ( unsigned char )*s ) ) ++s;
        
        while ( s != p && !isalpha( ( unsigned char )*--p ) );
    } while ( s != p && *s == *p && ++s );
    
    return s == p;
}

int main(void) 
{
    const char *s = "a bc, ba!";
    printf( "\"%s\" is palindrome: %s.\n", s, isPalindrome( s ) ? "true" : "false" );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
"a bc, ba!" is palindrome: true.
```